# Highcharts Displaying same data repeatedly

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

Thought I'd ask for a hand in this, am currently trying to code up a highcharts javascript file to display some data I have. I have been able to display the correct number of data sets, and on the correct graphs (they go into a time or proc graph) but I have an issue where ALL the graphs are using the same name & data, regardless of which graph they are on as well. Even though when i do an alert on where they are being assigned to their object arrays, they are all individual. Really unsure of what is happening.

where an Obj is:

```
{
    name: SERIES_NAME,
    data: SERIES_DATA,
}
```

The output graphs, instead of having the data as follows:

Graph Data: { Obj1, Obj2, Obj3...ObjN }, Showing multiple individual series.

I have:

Graph Data: { ObjN, ObjN, ObjN...ObjN },

They are all just ObjN. Even across the two graphs. All the data/names are the same.

Also all of this code is called from within a php $(document).ready(function())

```
function create_highchart(TIER,ARRAYS_STRING) {

        var chart;
        timestamp=document.getElementById("TIMESTAMP").value;
        var graph_dir = "graphs/capsim/"+timestamp+"/";

        var glue_outer = "___";
        var glue_inner = ":#:";
        var glue_csv="^";
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;

        var tier_names=[];
        var WL_names = [];
        var CSV_data=[];
        var CSVs = [];
        var CSV_det=[];
        var out_arrays=[];

        var time_ids = ['queue','util','arrival','thruput'];

        out_arrays = ARRAYS_STRING.split(glue_outer);
        tier_names = out_arrays[0].split(glue_inner);
        WL_names = out_arrays[1].split(glue_inner);
        CSVs = out_arrays[2].split(glue_inner);
        CSV_det = out_arrays[3].split(glue_inner);
        WL_num = WL_names.length;
        tier_names.push('Overall System');
        tier_max = tier_names.length;
        curr_tier_name = tier_names[TIER];

        while(i<CSVs.length){
            CSV_data[i]=[];
            data = CSVs[i].split(glue_csv);
            CSV_data[i]=data;
            i=i+1;
        }

        i=0;
        var TMP_series = {
                name: '',
                data: [],
        }

        var TIME_SERIES_DATA=[];
        var PROC_SERIES_DATA=[];
        var time_count=0;
        var proc_count=0;

        var x = [];
        var y = [];
        var cat = [];
        var out2 = [];

        var options_time={
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'hc_div2',
                type: 'scatter',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Highcharts Demo for Graphing',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Graph for '+curr_tier_name,
                x: -20
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Performance Metrics'
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        'X: '+this.x +' Y: '+ this.y

                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                           radius: 2,
                    }              
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: TIME_SERIES_DATA
        };                

        var options_proc={
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'hc_div1',
                type: 'scatter',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Highcharts Demo for Graphing',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Graph for '+curr_tier_name,
                x: -20
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Performance Metrics'
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    'X: '+this.x +' Y: '+ this.y
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2,
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: PROC_SERIES_DATA
        };

        var i=0;
        if(TIER==tier_max-1){
            TIER='OVR';
        };

        while(i<=CSV_det.length){
            csv = CSV_det[i+4];
            curr_data=CSV_data[(i/5)];
            csv_name = CSV_det[i+1];
            csv_tier = CSV_det[i+2];
            csv_wl = parseFloat(CSV_det[i+3])+1;

            wl_info = '';
            if(CSV_det[i+3] !='NA'){
                wl_info = ' Workload: '+csv_wl;
            };

            var j=0;
            var line = '';
            if(TIER==csv_tier){
                TMP_series.data = [];
                TMP_series.name = csv_name+wl_info;
                while(j<curr_data.length){
                    XY=curr_data[j].split(',');
                    X = parseFloat(XY[0]);
                    Y = parseFloat(XY[1]);
                    TMP_series.data.push([X,Y]);
                    j=j+1;
                }
                j=0;
                csv_type=csv.split('/')[3].split('_')[0];
                if($.inArray(csv_type,time_ids)==-1){
                    PROC_SERIES_DATA[proc_count]=[];
                    PROC_SERIES_DATA[proc_count]=TMP_series;
                    proc_count=proc_count+1;
                }else{
                    TIME_SERIES_DATA[time_count]=[];
                    TIME_SERIES_DATA[time_count]=TMP_series;
                    time_count=time_count+1;
                }
            }
            i=i+5;
        };
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options_proc);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options_time);
    }
```

A quick explanation on whats going on:

1. Initially parsing all the data into relevant bins from the arrays string
2. Creating the two highcharts that wil be displayed
3. Scanning over the CSVs to find ones that are relevant
4. For ones that are, reading their Data, and adding it to a TMP_series
5. Once all data is read, adding the TMP_series to the relevant graph data series

Any help is greatly apprecaited!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset TMP_series to a new object each time you generate a series.  Right now you are recycling the same object, and pushing references to the same object into the series arrays.  Modify the last bit of your code to read like this:

```
       if(TIER==csv_tier){
            TMP_series = {
                 name : csv_name+wl_info,
                 data : []
            };
            while(j<curr_data.length){
                XY=curr_data[j].split(',');
                X = parseFloat(XY[0]);
                Y = parseFloat(XY[1]);
                TMP_series.data.push([X,Y]);
                j=j+1;
            }
            j=0;
            csv_type=csv.split('/')[3].split('_')[0];
            if($.inArray(csv_type,time_ids)==-1){
                PROC_SERIES_DATA[proc_count]=[];
                PROC_SERIES_DATA[proc_count]=TMP_series;
                proc_count=proc_count+1;
            }else{
                TIME_SERIES_DATA[time_count]=[];
                TIME_SERIES_DATA[time_count]=TMP_series;
                time_count=time_count+1;
            }
        }
```

Notice how at the top of the if, I create a new object with the specified properties, and assign it to the reference TMP_series.  Remember, objects are passed by reference, so when you push objects into arrays, you are pushing a reference to the object, not a copy of the object.